# JNI in eclipse:Running the Java code

Tags: java, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

the problem is:when i am running the Java code an error occurs:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sample \\(library:sample.dll)\\ in java.library.path.
It seems that the library file is not accessible to the JVM.
How to ensure that the library file's location is in the classpath?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

and put your dll in the java.library.path path.

Comment: i did this step and obtained many paths:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows ......

which one should i use?Thanks